# How to forbid lazy-loading of child object due to serialization?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, asp.net-web-api

I'm using Entity Framework to pull back data to expose in a Web API service.  Our Model has a ProductDetails object, which has a Product object, which has a Category object. So, in my context called by my Get action, I ask it to include Product (but not Category):

```
results = context.ProductDetails.Include("Product");
```

So, in my service result, I get e.g. (XML shortened for typing):

```
<ProductDetails>
    ...
    <Product>
        ...
        <Category>
            <Name>Example Category name</>
            ...
        </>
        <CategoryId>1</>
    </>
    <ProductId>17</>
 </>
```

I presume that the serialization causes Category to get "lazy-loaded" even though I don't really want it to.  How do I avoid getting more than I asked for?  I'd like to get:

```
<ProductDetails>
    ...
    <Product>
        ...
        <Category i:nil="true"/>
        <CategoryId>1</>
    </>
    <ProductId>17</>
 </>
```

How do I query (or tell the serializer) to retain the CategoryId but not to retrieve the full Category?

EDIT, for reference, here's Product's model:

```
[Table("PRODUCT", Schema = "MySchema")]
public class ProductSqlModel
{
    private CustomTypeConverter _converter = new CustomTypeConverter();

    [Key]
    [Column("CODE")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public virtual int? Id { get; set; }

    [Column("CATEGORY_CODE")]
    public virtual int? CategoryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CATEGORY_ID")]
    public virtual CategorySqlModel Category { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

EDIT: I'm getting somewhat inconsistent behavior--the first load after an IIS reset, the data is as I want it.  If I reload the page, suddenly Category is fully populated.  Is this a clue?

Comment: Can you show the definition of `Category` in `Product`?

Comment: I would suggest to enforce eager loading by removing the `virtual` modifier. You will now have to explicitly load it using `.Include()` but generating the serialized data will now no longer contain the Category's data.

Comment: Removing the virtual modifier resulted in no change of behavior.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm getting somewhat inconsistent behavior--the first load after an IIS Reset, **the data is as I want it**.  But, if I reload the page, suddenly Category is fully populated, as for every subsequent load.  Is this a clue?

Comment: Removing virtual should return you a `null` value for Category if you don't explicitly or eagerly load it. I can't really say anything meaningful about the sudden data population. Is there any chance you can create a reproducible example that shows this in a minified environment? Can you show the exact code used for querying the database and configuring CategorySqlModel in EF?

Comment: Debugging, I find that the property is null the first time I get it (thus ruling out lazy loading), and populated every subsequent time. Maybe this is something with caching or the in-memory entities in the context?  How can I figure out what other code might be modifying the in-memory entities?

Answer (score 1):

I would also suspect lazy loading is the cause since serializers will access each property of the object in question. Perhaps you could turn off lazy loading for the entire context and just use eager loading? The following shows how to turn off lazy loading for the context:

```
public class SomeContext : DbContext 
{ 
    public SomeContext() 
    { 
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; 
    } 
}
```

You should end up with the serialized object containing the CategoryId, but not the Category object itself.

Comment: Please disregard previous comment. I checked, and this has already been done! LazyLoadingEnabled is false. Weird.  What else could it be?